# Push an item to array of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I am having an array like below and trying to push the item on map, but i am not able to push, Please tell what wrong i am doing here.

```
firstClassPrices: [
  [
    "Kan ej ombokas",
    "431",
    "SEK",
    "Företagspris"
  ],
  [
    "Kan ombokas",
    "525",
    "SEK",
    "Företagspris"
  ]
]
```

trying to push '1' like below:

```
 let ticketi = firstClassPrices.map((price) => {
      price.push("1");
    });
```

i need o/p as

```
firstClassPrices: [
      [
        "Kan ej ombokas",
        "431",
        "SEK",
        "Företagspris",
         "1"
      ],
      [
        "Kan ombokas",
        "525",
        "SEK",
        "Företagspris",
         "1"
      ]
    ]
```

Comment: [Your code already works](https://jsfiddle.net/k53qsbt1/). You're only using `.map()` while not returning any elements from its callback function so the return value (which you store in `ticketi` will only contain `undefined` values. But the original `firstClassPrices` will contain what you are looking for.

Comment: if "1" is already there in array how to skip the push

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return the `price`

```js
const firstClassPrices = [
  [
    "Kan ej ombokas",
    "431",
    "SEK",
    "Företagspris"
  ],
  [
    "Kan ombokas",
    "525",
    "SEK",
    "Företagspris"
  ]
];

 let ticketi = firstClassPrices.map((price) => {
      // skip if price already includes 1
      if (!price.includes("1")) {
        price.push("1");
      }
      return price;
    });

console.log(ticketi);
```

Comment: In this code, both `firstClassPrices` and `ticketi` reference the same nested arrays. There is little added value in using `.map()` if you are going to modify the original array also.

Comment: if "1" is already there in array how to skip the push

Comment: @Sudhir I updated the code with this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach mutates the old array and maps `undefined`.

---

Instead, you could map the old and new content of the array.

This approach does not mutate the old data.

```
let ticketi = firstClassPrices.map(price => [...price, '1']);
```

Comment: Notice that according to OP: `1` should be of type `string`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Code:

```js
const firstClassPrices = [["Kan ej ombokas","431","SEK","Företagspris"],["Kan ombokas","525","SEK","Företagspris"]]

const ticketi = firstClassPrices.map(p => p.concat('1'))

console.log(ticketi)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to mutate the original arrays, you can use the function `Array.prototype.forEach`.

The problem you're facing is regarding the missing return value inside of the map's handler, so basically, the handler is returning `undefined`

```js
const array = [  [    "Kan ej ombokas",    "431",    "SEK",    "Företagspris"  ],  [    "Kan ombokas",    "525",    "SEK",    "Företagspris"  ]],
      handler = (a) => a.push("1");

array.forEach(handler);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```